# Trying to create a csv using python, and getting "list indices" error

Tags: python, csv

In my last question, I asked how to get python to assign a set of values to phrases in a csv files.  I was told to create a list of tuples, and this worked great.

Currently my list, called clean_titles looks like this:

```
[('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('b', 2),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3),
 ('c', 3)]
```

Now I want to take the list, and export it to as CSV file.  I want the name of the phrases in one column and the assigned number in another column.

```
with open("fiancee_wordfreq.csv" , "wb") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)  
  for val in clean_titles:
     writer.writerow([val])
```

But I keep getting an error message that "list indices must be integers not unicode"

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can run your code without error. Although I doubt you want the brackets around `val`.

Comment: And I'm going to assume that `fiancee_wordfreq.csv` isn't being used for nefarious purposes... :)

Comment: If you're using Python3 there is no need for the 'b' in the mode argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My answer is for Python3)

You are opening the file in "bytes" mode. It worked for me when I removed the "b" argument:

```
with open("testabc.csv" , "w") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)  
  for val in clean_titles:
     writer.writerow(val)
```

Also, you can just use a built-in `writerows` function to be less verbose:

```
with open("testabc.csv" , "w") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)  
  writer.writerows(clean_titles)
```